# Is Ubuntu Crontabe Have Memory Limit?

Tags: django, postgresql, cron

I tried to use crontab to handle my django commands.

```
../virtualenv/env/bin/python manage.py my_commands
```

But there are usually show

```
django.db.utils.InterfaceError: connection already closed
Error!! SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

When I use "Screen" to open a terminal to execute that script, The commands will be fine and also done the job.

That's what I am doubting crontab have memory limit.

Comment: When your script is run by cron, it may have a different environment, such as current directory and $path.

Comment: Hi, joop, When I use cron, I will use .sh to run my virutalenv like:  export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon my_env